# While gives "Found one too many { characters without a } to match it" when the same as an if statement does not

Tags: java, compiler-errors, while-loop, processing, curly-braces

When the following code is run it won't compile and I get an error telling me, *"Found one too many { characters without a } to match it."*.

```
while (thePlayer.position.x > thePlayer.position2.x - 60) { 
              println("x2 =" + thePlayer.position2.x);
              thePlayer.position.x = thePlayer.position.x - 1;
              println("x =" + thePlayer.position.x);
            }
            else {
              thePlayer.position2.x = thePlayer.position.x;
              println("complete");
            }
```

However, when I change it to the sample below (an if statement) it compiles fine and runs through where the only change is substituting 'while' for 'if'.

```
if (thePlayer.position.x > thePlayer.position2.x - 60) { 
              println("x2 =" + thePlayer.position2.x);
              thePlayer.position.x = thePlayer.position.x - 1;
              println("x =" + thePlayer.position.x);
            }
            else {
              thePlayer.position2.x = thePlayer.position.x;
              println("complete");
            }
```

I'm really confused by this...

Comment: `while` loop block cannot have a `else` block following it. Only `if` block can!

Comment: Interestingly enough, Python has a `while..else` construct. But, since Java does not, you need to rethink what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `while..else` construct in Java (although Python has one and it's rather nifty).

So, there are two possibilities depending on what you're actually trying to achieve.

First, if you want the `else` block to run regardless of the `while` block, simply place it afterwards:

```
while (thePlayer.position.x > thePlayer.position2.x - 60) { 
    println("x2 =" + thePlayer.position2.x);
    thePlayer.position.x = thePlayer.position.x - 1;
    println("x =" + thePlayer.position.x);
}
thePlayer.position2.x = thePlayer.position.x;
println("complete");
```

That will loop until the condition becomes false then execute the remaining code.

On the other hand, if you want the `else` block to run *only if the* `while` *block didn't run* (mimicking Python's `while..else` construct), that requires something like a `while-within-if` setup:

```
if (thePlayer.position.x > thePlayer.position2.x - 60) { 
    while (thePlayer.position.x > thePlayer.position2.x - 60) { 
        println("x2 =" + thePlayer.position2.x);
        thePlayer.position.x = thePlayer.position.x - 1;
        println("x =" + thePlayer.position.x);
    }
} else {
    thePlayer.position2.x = thePlayer.position.x;
    println("complete");
}
```

There, the `else` clause only executes if the `while` loop ran one or more iterations.

You just need to select the behaviour you want and choose one of the options above.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have an `else` statement without an `if` statement. Change:

```
while (thePlayer.position.x > thePlayer.position2.x - 60) { 
              println("x2 =" + thePlayer.position2.x);
              thePlayer.position.x = thePlayer.position.x - 1;
              println("x =" + thePlayer.position.x);
            }
            else {
              thePlayer.position2.x = thePlayer.position.x;
              println("complete");
            }
```

to:

```
while (thePlayer.position.x > thePlayer.position2.x - 60) {
  println("x2 =" + thePlayer.position2.x);
  thePlayer.position.x = thePlayer.position.x - 1;
  println("x =" + thePlayer.position.x);
}

thePlayer.position2.x = thePlayer.position.x;
println("complete");
```

This will run the loop and when the condition becomes false it will run the lines after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because an 'else' after a while loop is wrong syntax.
This will work:

```
while(thePlayer.position.x >      thePlayer.position2.x - 60)
{
println("x2 ="   thePlayer.position2.x);
thePlayer.position.x = thePlayer.position.x - 1;
println("x ="   thePlayer.position.x);
}

thePlayer.position2.x = thePlayer.position.x;
println("complete");
```

Hope this helps.....